# Can I employ back-ticks and parentheses with doxygen @ref?

Tags: comments, doxygen, code-documentation, cross-reference, backticks

I want a doxygen comment in my  C++ code to refer to a certain function; say, in a different namespace: `foo::bar()`. And let's ignore the possibility that this function is overloaded. And I would also like the function's name to be set the same way as content within backticks in my doxygen comments.

With that in mind, which of the following are supposed to produce the effect I've described?

```
@ref foo::bar
@ref foo::bar()
@ref `foo::bar`
@ref `foo::bar()`
```

or - perhaps something else?

Comment: "which of the following should I be using?" is opinion based in my mind. What does work?  what doesn't? Which version of doxygen.

Comment: @albert: Clarified I want to know which of these is supposed to work.

Comment: Well, the last 2 emit a warning as they don't contain valid labels.

Comment: @albert: But don't the first two result in link text that is non-monospace?

Comment: They are with the letter type / style that is defined in the doxygen.css file. See the `a.el` in doxygen.css (in my case it is line 216).

Comment: @albert: Could you expand this comment into an answer? Possibly with a relevant snippet of the `a.el` file?

Comment: `a.el` is not a file but an entry in doxygen.css

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the `\ref` command states:

> \ref  ["(text)"]
>
> Creates a reference to a named section, subsection, page or anchor. For HTML documentation the reference command will generate a link to the section. For a section or subsection the title of the section will be used as the text of the link. For an anchor the optional text between quotes will be used or  if no text is specified. For LATEX documentation the reference command will generate a section number for sections or the text followed by a page number if  refers to an anchor.

With the `\ref` command the first argument is the `<name>` and a `<name>` cannot contain a backtick.

To obtain the requested possibility of a mono spaced link one can for HTML (only!) adjust / extend the used entry in the style sheet.

As a starter:
In the default doxygen stylesheet `doxygen.css` we have:

```
a.el {
        font-weight: bold;
}
```

By changing this entry to e.g.

```
a.el {
        font-family: monospace, fixed;
        font-weight: normal;
}
```

Best is not to redefine the `doxygen.css` and give this as setting `HTML_STYLESHEET`,
but create a new, extra, stylesheet and specify this in `HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET`.

Note that this will influence **all** links not only the `\ref` ones.

Comment: Is `a.el` used only  for links generated due to `@ref` or `@see`? Or also to other links?

Comment: Also for other links

Comment: I see. So is there nothing I can do to change the style for a specific @ref/@see link? Or for a subset of them?

Comment: No not really, only create an enhancement request in the doxygen bug tracer. the only think one could think about is use and `ALIAS` in combination with `\htmlonly` or maybe `\anchor` but this would be very difficult and tricky and I'm not sure this would lead to a result.